# How do I make a query of like in MongoDB c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In MongoDB if I want to make a LIKE statement I do:

```
 db.users.find({"name": /m/})
```

And it works great!! How do I do it in c#?

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("city", "/M/");
```

Does not return anything!

Answer (score 2):

Use a **[Filter Definition Builder](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/#filter-definition-builder)** with a regular expression filter **[`Regex()`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_Regex.htm)** as follows:

```
var search = "M";
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Regex("city", search);
```

Comment: regex is case sensitive. You can not search 'm' in city with same Regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Use Regex,
var search = "M";
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Regex("city", "^" + search + ".*"); 
// ^ - For Starts with
// . - any character
// * - for any number of previous "."
```